# Android: Check Notifications

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android and am trying to play with what I think should be a simple true/false statement. 
 What I want to do ( and am not sure if it is even possible) is simply check to see if there are any notifications of any sort pending. So basically if that led on the top of the android device is flashing from a text message, Facebook post, voice mail or whatever I can return True to a Boolean.

At this point I don't need to do anything with them. I just want to know if its possible (if so, how) to see if there anything waiting and not clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend getting more acclimated with the Android platform by doing a few tutorials or reading a book or two before you go any further.

However, to answer your question, you cannot check for notifications from other applications in the status bar.  You can however control your own notifications through the `Notification` and `NotificationManager` classes.  Here is their documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Comment: Thank you for that. If there is no way to check to see if there are pending notifications then my little learning idea wont work.